# How can i solve the index out of range error of python?

Tags: python

I'm new in python and im trying to work with an existent code for my work, im gettint an error of index, that i cant understand, ia have tried mutltiples option that i already seen but im still have the same problem, can anyone help me, please?

This is the code:

```
Repo = []
for p in Y:
    Repo.append((p/SUM_Y)**(0))#LABEL_WEIGHT[hoja]))

distributions = [
    ['Data after standard scaling',
    pd.DataFrame(StandardScaler().fit_transform(X),columns = ['x','y'])],
    ['Data after min-max scaling',
                pd.DataFrame(MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(X),columns = ['x','y'])],
    ['Data after max-abs scaling',
                pd.DataFrame(MaxAbsScaler().fit_transform(X),columns = ['x','y'])],
    ['Data after robust scaling',
                pd.DataFrame(RobustScaler(quantile_range=(25, 75)).fit_transform(X),columns = ['x','y'])],
    ['Data after power transformation (Yeo-Johnson)',
            pd.DataFrame(PowerTransformer(method='yeo-johnson').fit_transform(X),columns = ['x','y'])],
    ['Data after power transformation (Box-Cox)',
            pd.DataFrame(PowerTransformer(method='box-cox').fit_transform(X),columns = ['x','y'])],
    ['Data after quantile transformation (gaussian pdf)',
            pd.DataFrame(QuantileTransformer(output_distribution='normal')
            .fit_transform(X),columns = ['x','y'])],
    ['Data after quantile transformation (uniform pdf)',
            pd.DataFrame(QuantileTransformer(output_distribution='uniform')
            .fit_transform(X),columns = ['x','y'])],
    ['Data after sample-wise L2 normalizing',
            pd.DataFrame(Normalizer().fit_transform(X),columns = ['x','y'])],
]


for j in range(0,len(distributions)):
    #kmeans = sklearn.cluster.k_means(distributions[j][1],n_clusters=4, random_state=52365,sample_weight=None)#.fit(distributions[j][1])
    LL = [1/distributions[j][1].shape[0] for i in np.arange(distributions[j][1].shape[0])]
            #print(LL)


    try:
        kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=4, random_state=52365).fit(distributions[j][1],sample_weight=Repo)
        centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_
        labels = fct.sorting_by_center_of_mass(kmeans.cluster_centers_,kmeans.labels_)
        distributions[j].append(1)
        label_color = [LABEL_COLOR_MAP[l] for l in labels]
        distributions[j].append(labels)
        distributions[j].append(silhouette_score(distributions[j][1], kmeans.labels_))
        distributions[j].append(centroids)
    except:
        distributions[j].append(0)
        continue

print(distributions[INDICE_TRUE][0])

Selector = {}
for r in range(0,len(distributions)):
    if distributions[r][2] == 0:
        pass
    else:
        Selector[r] = distributions[r][4]

INDICE_TRUE = list({k: v for k, v in sorted(Selector.items(), key=lambda item: item[1],reverse=True)}.keys())[0]
```

and im getting this error:

---

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-480-d452250e06c1> in <module>
    227             Selector[r] = distributions[r][4]
    228 
--> 229     INDICE_TRUE = list({k: v for k, v in sorted(Selector.items(), key=lambda item: item[1],reverse=True)}.keys())[0]
    230 
    231     B_F_1['Label'] = distributions[INDICE_TRUE][3]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: what is the output of the following: `list({k: v for k, v in sorted(Selector.items(), key=lambda item: item[1],reverse=True)}.keys())`

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop which assigns to to Selector is not guaranteed to make any assignments. If distributions[r][2] == 0 for every r, then Selector will be empty.

```
for r in range(0,len(distributions)):
    if distributions[r][2] == 0:
        pass
    else:
        Selector[r] = distributions[r][4]
```

By implication, this thing, whatever it is, cannot have the zero index at the end:

```
INDICE_TRUE = list({k: v for k, v in sorted(Selector.items(), key=lambda item: item[1],reverse=True)}.keys())[0]
```

My personal 2 cents: Pandas is hard, Numpy is hard, data structures are hard. If you're going to start out by mixing them all together in bad copy-pasted code you are going to struggle.

I say this code is bad because there is a lot of nasty stuff in here. For example, catching a bare exception is a recognised anti pattern, variable names don't follow PEP, there's magic numbers everywhere, and far too many compound statements to be able to make sense of what's going on. Start with a good tutorial on the standard libary, then learn numpy, then pandas, or you will struggle.

Answer (score 0):

It's very dangerous to hide errors with generic try/catch:

```
try:
  <something failed>
except:
  distributions[j].append(0)
  continue
```

In this case:

1. you don't know which error was found [generic exception]
2. you add a non valid element to j
3. final *continue*, will hide inconsistent states of your algorithm